# How to find out if a Perl hash is multidimensional?

Tags: perl, hash

Assuming I have a hash like this:

```
$hash_ref = {

  'hashes' => {
    'h1' => { 'klf' => '1', 'moomooland' => '1' },
    'h2' => { 'klf' => '2', 'moomooland' => '2' },
    'h3' => { 'klf' => '3', 'moomooland' => '3' }
  },

  'keys' => {
    'k1' => 'key1',
    'k2' => 'key2',
    'k3' => 'key3'
  }

}
```

How could I find out, as easy as possible, that `hashes` contains 3 more hashes, while `keys` contains 3 key/value pairs?

`ref` will return `HASH` for both of them, and I am not sure if it is possible to maybe find out the depth of these hashes.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I'm wondering why you'd want to know this. That may help in deciding a suitable course of action. e.g. Do you want to return the deepest chain, or the depth of all different branches?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Traversing a multi-dimensional hash in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160175/traversing-a-multi-dimensional-hash-in-perl)

Comment: I'd need to know this so I can invoke different action depending whether I am getting 3 hashes or 3 key/value pairs. So, I don't necessarily need to know the exact depth, if I can differentiate between these 2 in some other way. I see your link to other question now, but I hoped this could be done without using recursion :)

Comment: That's not quite a duplicate, but the approaches listed there can be adapted to count the number of levels.  There's no built-in way to do that.

Comment: I am using Data::Dumper a lot, for dumping data, but I don't see how I could use it in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to know if a hash is multi-dimensional, you can iterate over its values and stop if a reference is found:

```
my $is_multi_dimensional = 0;

for my $value (values %$hash_ref) {
    if ('HASH' eq ref $value) {
        $is_multi_dimensional = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

or you can use the `each()` function:

```
while (my (undef, $value) = each %$hash_ref) {
    if ('HASH' eq ref $value) {
        $is_multi_dimensional = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is quite brilliant. So simple, yet so logical and effective. Argh, why didn't I think of this? :) Thank you Eugene, this works perfectly well for what I need, although now I realize that wording of my question doesn't really explain that this is what I was looking for, rather than getting exact/actual depth of a hash. Whoops.

Comment: Are you sure each() is any more efficient that values()? Since it uses the internal iterator, it may short circuit which helps for giant hashes, but it has the general drawback of using the (global!) hash iterator. each() is a misfeature, IMO.

Comment: @tsee: it's more efficient for bigger hashes, because it doesn't create an intermediate list of values. And it's the only way to go for very big (e.g. tied) hashes. Of course, one should remember that there's a single iterator for each hash in the program, by design.

Comment: It is only multidimensional if the ref points to another hash; or, arguably another array.. It certainly wouldn't be multidimensional just because it has a globref, subref, or scalar ref.. This isn't right.

Comment: @eugene y -- Actually, neither does `values` it creates a list of **references** to the values of the hash. `perl -e'my %foo=(bar=>'baz'); $_=1 for values %foo; use Data::Dumper; die Dumper \%foo'` and at that, yours does in fact, require the copying of each and key and value to a different local scalar namely `$key`, and `$value`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also [`first`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for this:

```
use List::Util 'first';
say 'is multi-dimensional' if first { ref } values %$hash_ref;

# explicitly check for HASH ref this time
my $how_many_md_hashes = grep { 'HASH' eq ref } values %$hash_ref;
```

NB. `first` (part of [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm) core module) short circuits so is ideal for conditionals and is probably the fastest of all possible options.

/I3az/

Comment: You can use 'any' instead of 'first' if you only care about truthiness rather than the actual value that matched: `use List::MoreUtils 'any'; my $is_multi_dimensional = any { ref } values %$hash_ref;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one to know the depth of Perl hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $hash_ref = {

  'hashes' => {
    'h1' => { 'klf' => '1', 'moomooland' => '1' },
    'h2' => { 'klf' => '2', 'moomooland' => '2' },
    'h3' => { 'klf' => '3', 'moomooland' => '3' }
  },

  'keys' => {
    'k1' => 'key1',
    'k2' => 'key2',
    'k3' => 'key3'
  }

};
print_nested_hash($hash_ref, 0);

sub print_nested_hash {
    my $hash_ref = shift;
    my $depth = shift;
    foreach my $key (sort keys %{$hash_ref}) {
        print '    ' x $depth, $key, "\n";

        if (ref($hash_ref->{$key}) eq "HASH") {
            print_nested_hash($hash_ref->{$key}, $depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
hashes
    h1
        klf
        moomooland
    h2
        klf
        moomooland
    h3
        klf
        moomooland
keys
    k1
    k2
    k3
```