# Efficient way of printing hash of hash of arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

I am writing a script that involves printing the contents of a hash of a hash of arrays.

ex (pseudo code):

```
my %hash = ();
$hash{key1}{key2} = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', . . .];
```

or

```
$hash{key1}{key2} = @array_of_values;
```

Basically I want to be able to do this for any number of key combinations and be able to loop through all of the possible key/value pairs (or probably more correctly stated as key,key/array pairs since each value is actually an array of values and each array has 2 keys associated with it) and print the output in the following format:

"key1, key2, value1, value2, value3, . . .\n"

ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize hash
my %hash = ();
my $string1 = "string1";
my $string2 = "string2";

# push strings onto arrays stored in hash
push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string1;
push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string1;

# print elements of hash
# (want to do this as a loop for all possible key/value pairs)
local $, = ',';
print "a, b, ";
print @{$hash{a}{b}};
print "\n";
print "c, d, ";
print @{$hash{c}{d}};
print "\n";

system ('pause');
```

The output from this code is shown below:

```
a, b, string1,string2
c, d, string2,string1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I was thinking about using the `each` operator but it appears to only work for one dimensional hashes. (`each` only returns one key value pair, it does not work correctly when there are 2 keys involved)

How can I streamline this code to traverse through the hash in a loop and print the desired output regardless of how big my hash gets?

Comment: Related: [Traversing a multi-dimensional hash in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/160175/176646)

Comment: Its should perhaps be added that in case you do not know, there are modules which will print data structures for you, such as `Data::Dumper` (core module), or `Data::Dump`. E.g. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a nested loop  ... there's likely a way to do this with `map` that is harder to remember and less readable ;-)  (speaking only for myself of course - I look forward to seeing a `map` solution appear here!):

```
#!perl -l
my %hash = ();
$hash{key1}{key2} = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3',];

for my $outer (keys %hash) { 
    for my $inner (keys $hash{$outer}) { 
       print join(', ', $outer, $inner, @{ $hash{$outer}{$inner} } )
    } 
}
```

**output:**

```
key1, key2, value1, value2, value3
```

There's also [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer), [`Data::Seek`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Seek),[`Data::Dive`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dive) and several other convenience modules if things are really complicated.  Some require the use of hash references though which may complicate a simpler solution or make a larger and more difficult problem more easily possible ...

Cheers,

**EDIT**: moved "nested map" into a separate answer.

Comment: I agree, I would also love to see a `map` solution here. :) Of the solutions posted this seems to be the simplest and most straightforward so far.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 ... I edited in a `map` "answer" to my response ... punishing me if you see fit! :-)

Comment: Your code isn't actually printing out the answer that the OP asked for, unfortunately... :\  I've added a `map` version to my answer (though I do like the anonymous sub in yours!).

Comment: @tjwrona1992 maybe the `map` approach would benefit from 5.20 style [postfix derferencing](http://perltricks.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature--postfix-dereferencing) ;-)

Comment: @ i alarmed alien - I assumed the OP would integrate things into his larger script/application.  Will edit up to snuff later. Cheers.

Comment: @G.Cito His or her application. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Using `each` works perfectly fine even for a multilevel hash, you just have to make sure that the argument is a hash. Here is an example of how you can do it. I also showed how I would initialize that hash of yours.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

my $string1 = "string1";
my $string2 = "string2";
my %hash = (
    a => { 
        b => [ $string1, $string2 ],
    },
    c => {
        d => [ $string2, $string1 ],
    }
);

for my $key (keys %hash) {
    while (my ($k, $v) = each %{ $hash{$key} }) {
        say join ", ", $key, $k, @$v;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
c, d, string2, string1
a, b, string1, string2
```

Note the simplicity of using `@$v` to get to your innermost array, rather than the somewhat cumbersome alternative `@{ $hash{$key}{$k} }`.

Comment: +1 `@$v` is succinct - but if one is a follower of PBP @{ $hash{$key}{$k} } is clearer ;-)  I wonder how postfix dereferencing will play out in syntax usage and practice.

Answer (score 4):

This is tidiest with a recursive subroutine, and since it will only recurse a few time it isn't a wasteful solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my ($string1, $string2) = qw/ string1 string2 /;

push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string1;
push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string1;

print_data(\%hash);

sub print_data {
    my ($ref, $prefix) = (@_, '');

   if (ref $ref eq 'ARRAY') {
      print $prefix, join(', ', @$ref), "\n";
   }
   else {
      print_data($ref->{$_}, "$prefix$_, ") for sort keys %$ref;
   }
}
```

**output**

```
a, b, string1, string2
c, d, string2, string1
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't stated why you want to print the contents of your HoHoA (hash of hash of arrays). If it's for debugging purposes I'd use either Data::Dumper (core) or Data::Dump (on CPAN).

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
print Dumper \%hash;
```

or

```
use Data::Dump qw(pp);
pp \%hash;
```

Assuming that there's a reason you want the output formatted per your sample (and that it's always and only a HoHoA) I'd use a nested loop:

```
while (my ($ok, $ov) = each %hash) {
    while (my ($ik, $iv) = each %$ov) {
        say join ',', @$iv;
    }
}
```

I don't recommend using `map`. It's best used for list transformation rather than flow control and it's awkward to keep track of the outer and inner keys with nested `map` blocks both using `$_` for different things. Because you and G. Cito expressed interest in seeing one, though, here it is:

```
say foreach map {
    my $o = $_;
    map {
        my $i = $_;
        join ',', $o, $i, @{$hash{$o}{$i}}
    } keys %{$hash{$o}};
} keys %hash;
```

Comment: nice :-) I just did a double map (see above) ... which as I mentioned seems less readable (to me) and no more efficient but errm seems cool heh ;-)  Cheers.

Comment: Isn't the `foreach` surplus to requirements since you've got `map` there doing basically the same job?

Comment: @Michael Carman the HoHoA is mirroring the structure of a database that I am working with and the arrays store strings of values to import into the database at the end of running my script.  +1 for the nice solution using `each` though :)

Answer (score 2):

To print a hash of hash of arrays, you can iterate through the data structure using `foreach` or `for my`:

```
# keys of the outer hash
foreach my $oh (keys %hash) {
    # keys of the inner hash
    foreach my $ih (keys %{$hash{$oh}}) {
        # $hash{$oh}{$ih} is the array, so it can be printed thus:
        print join(", ", $oh, $ih, @{$hash{$oh}{$ih}}) . "\n";

        # or you can iterate through the items like this:
        # foreach my $arr (@{$hash{$oh}{$ih}})
        # {   doSomethingTo($arr); }

    }
}
```

And for all you cartography fans, here's a `map` version:

```
map { my $oh = $_; 
    map { say join( ", ", $oh, $_, @{$hash{$oh}{$_}} )  } keys %{$hash{$_}}
} keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about it and came up with one possible solution.  If anyone has a more elegant solution I would love to see it. Thanks!

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize hash
my %hash = ();
my $string1 = "string1";
my $string2 = "string2";

# push strings onto arrays stored in hash
push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string1;
push @{$hash{a}{b}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string2;
push @{$hash{c}{d}}, $string1;

# prints hash of hash of arrays in a loop :)
my @keys1 = keys %hash;
for my $key1 (@keys1) {
    my @keys2 = keys $hash{$key1};
    for my $key2 (@keys2) {
        local $" = ', ';
        print "$key1, $key2, @{$hash{$key1}{$key2}}";
        print "\n";
    }
}

system ('pause');
```

This solution doesn't care about the order of the keys though so it will print in a random order.

Output:

```
c, d, string2, string1
a, b, string1, string2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: If you only use the keys once, there's no need to store them in arrays, i.e. you can simply do `for my $key1 (keys %hash) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks! that simplifies my code down to `for my $key1 (keys %hash) { for my $key2 (keys $hash{$key1}) { ... }}` sorry for the terrible format, its difficult to format code in a comment.

Comment: You can only call `keys` on a hash, so your inner loop should actually be `for my $key2 ( keys %{ $hash{$key1} } ) { ... }`

Comment: hmm it appeared to work without casting it as a hash, that's funny.  I will add the "%{}" just for good coding practice but it appears to work either way.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It is documented in [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html): `Starting with Perl 5.14, keys can take a scalar EXPR, which must contain a reference to an unblessed hash or array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically. This aspect of keys is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl.`

Comment: So, in other words, you *can* use a hash ref, but its better not to.

Comment: @TLP Thanks. Somebody mentioned that before and I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

I asked for it **:-(** ... a "nested map" (??).

```
#!perl -l
my %hash = ();
$hash{key1}{key2} = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3',];
map{ &{ sub{
   map{ print for @{$hash{$_[0]}{$_}}} keys $hash{$_} }}($_)} keys %hash;
```

**output:**

```
value1
value2
value3
```

**NB:** I think technically (behind the scenes) it's still a loop and no more efficient. It seems that if you "nest" the calls to `map` and wrap the inner `map{}` with an anonymous `sub` (the `{& sub { ..` bit) then you can reference the outer `map` topic values via `@_` (*i.e.* in `$_[0]` as they come in to the inner `map` ... but only if they are in list context `($_)` ... errm (?!?) OK I'm just grasping here.

Anyway, it works but looks messier than it should - possibly because it is an "[anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)".  One benefit is that it makes "nested `for` loops" seem much less messy and easier to read.

Comment: Nice and confusing. Just the way I like it :)

Comment: :)  I must be missing something, but in perl6 it appears this works:  `my %h =  key1 => key2 => <value1 value2 value3> ; 
"{%h.kv} ".say;`.

Comment: Woah now that's some strange Perl code! What are the "."s for? I've never seen `%h.kv` or a quote with a `.say` after it.

Comment: perl6 ... very different :-)